# Returning multiple rows from a single table by checking the values from different columns using CASE WHEN condition

Tags: google-bigquery, case

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN T1.COL1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
        WHEN T1.COL2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'B'
        WHEN T1.COL3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'C'
        WHEN T1.COL4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'D' 
    END AS ALPH
FROM 
    DB.TABLE1 T1;
```

Based on this logic, I want to check if required number of columns from `table1` is not null and populate a default value for each check, but if I use this logic, I am only getting 'A' to be populated, but COL2, COL3 and all doesn't have any null values, so all the required default values needs to be populated.

Current output:

```
ALPH
-----
A
```

Expected output:

```
ALPH
-----
A
B
C
```

Source data:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
---- |----  | ---- | ----
RD   |YU    | HU   | *null*
BL   |GH    | AB   |  bn
WH   |BN    | BC   |  CH
```

I am confused. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve? Post some example of source and destination data

Comment: Edited the question with expected output. I just wanted to check if the source data is not null and populate a default value.

Comment: Yes, but the source data is missing

Answer (score 0):

The query you wrote generates a single row for each selected row, furthermore CASE WHEN stops at the first satisfied condition

A possible solution can be this:

```sql
SELECT 'A' ALPH 
FROM db.table1
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'B' ALPH 
FROM db.table1
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'C' ALPH 
FROM db.table1
WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'D' ALPH 
FROM db.table1
WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
```

Which returns:

| ALPH |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| A |
| B |
| B |
| B |
| C |
| C |
| C |
| D |
| D |

If you also have an *id* in your table you can select it and finally sort by *id* and *ALPH* for a more interesting result:

```sql
SELECT (

    SELECT id, 'A' ALPH 
    FROM db.table1
    WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 'B' ALPH 
    FROM db.table1
    WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 'C' ALPH 
    FROM db.table1
    WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 'D' ALPH 
    FROM db.table1
    WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
    
) qAll

ORDER BY id, ALPH
```

| id | ALPH |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 3 | D |